# How to react to toggle menu bar in electron?

Tags: electron

I'm building and app that has exact bounds which should remain whatever you do. So it's not resizable. How do I react and then resize the window in the main process, when the menubar is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

The `resize` event should be emitted by `window`, when the dimension of the viewport change. You listen to that even and then you either send that information via IPC to the main process and change the window via `win.setSize(width, height[, animate])` or you can do the same thing from the renderer side. You can get the current window with `remote.getCurrentWindow()`.

Comment: Yes thats a way to react. Thanks for your answer. I thought there would be a way to do this directly through an event on the main window in the main process.

Comment: The BrowserWindow has a `resize` event too, but I think it would not fire when you toggle the menu bar, because the actual size of the window stays the same.